# Regex extracts one symbol more than needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract number from string:

```
var ss = klase.match(/[col-lg-]\d+/);
```

However, it extracts `-1` for example instead of just `1`.

Why it is so ?

String example: `draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle dragged col-lg-8`

Comment: Please give an example of the string.

Comment: What's wrong with `\d+` alone ?

Comment: Please provide better examples. What do you want to match? (-1 doesn't help us because it doesn't explain the `[col-lg-]`.)

Comment: `[]` defines a character CLASS. e.g. "if any of the characters inside the [] match any single character". so you're not looking for the wordl "col", you'r elooking for the letters `c` or `o` or `l`, etc... and `-` is a range operator in ther etoo. so `c`, `o`, letters from `l` to `l` (pointless), etc...

Comment: `-` is used for groups like `a-z`, instead is a part of the group `[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> String example: `draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle dragged col-lg-8`

Based on this, you don't want to match the characters individually (which is what the `[]` does), you want to match `col-lg-#` literally.  If that's the case.  And since you also want to only get the number, wrap the `\d+` in a capture group, which will be returned in a `.match()` on the string.

```
/col-lg-(\d+)/
```

This would probably fit your needs better.

To use this in a script:

```
var example = 'draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle dragged col-lg-8';
var colNum = example.match(/col-lg-(\d+)/)[1];

console.log(colNum);
// 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group your expected result:

```
/col-lg-(\d+)/
```

Example:

```
var output = 'col-lg-1'.match(/col-lg-(\d+)/),
    result = output[1]; // first group - result: 1
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this can be simplified to `/[colg-](\d+)/`. Maybe give a JS example of extracting the group?

Answer (score 0):

Replace brackets with paranthesis:

```
var ss = klase.match(/(col-lg-)\d+/);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the pattern `col-lg` before matching the 1 (as I presume in your question) consider using the regexp : `(?=[^col-lg-])\d+` which will check that `col-lg-` precedes your number.

Then simply get your match back like that :

```
//assuming that klasses contains col-lg-2 for example

var ss = klase.match(/(?=[^col-lg-])\d+/);
var result = ss[0]; //result has now the number you wanted, 2
```